# What animal / bird can be heard in this evening sound recording from Western Washington, USA?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology, bioacoustics

We heard this animal outside in Western Washington (Port Townsend area) during the late evening. I think it is a bird, but it honestly sounds sort of like some creepy woman singing or something. The audio is linked below. The sound (in the audio) was repeated for a long time at random intervals averaging probably every ten seconds.

https://clyp.it/tzybty1w

Anyone know for certain?

Comment: If I exclude the humming noise, the call is quite clear. But do you have any more longer-records?

Comment: The sound is approx ranging 200 Hz to 2000 Hz with most-occurred components belong approx 500 to 600 Hz. seems so , when filtered with any media player's equalizer.

Comment: That is the only sound clip I have...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the same question on another forum here: http://www.birdforum.net/showthread.php?p=3454684.

It looks like another possibility is a **barred owl**. It also [sounds somewhat similar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtRPYpklhiA).

Answer (score 3):

My guess is an owl, possibly a great horned owl, which are found in the [area](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=owls+in+western+washington&gws_rd=cr&ei=IQnZV8GdMMLO0gT6gqCQAg) and can [sound similar](http://www.learner.org/jnorth/sounds/Owl_GreatHorned_Duet.mp3).

Alternatively, it could be a mourning dove, which [sounds similar again](http://www.learner.org/jnorth/sounds/Dove_Mourning.mp3), and is [common throughout the USA](http://www.birdweb.org/birdweb/bird/mourning_dove).

Comment: Not a mourning dove; pattern wrong.  Owl is highly likely; Barred Owl suggested in other answer is better fit than Great Horned. Compare at Cornell site:allaboutbirds.org

Comment: @mgkrebbs I agree.

Answer (score 1):

This does sound like the characteristic "who cooks for you" call of a distant [**barred owl** (*Strix varia*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barred_owl). You can hear this call at [All About Birds](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Barred_Owl/sounds) run by Cornell Ornithology Lab.

- The [recording by
  Andrew Spencer](https://macaulaylibrary.org/asset/21681321) is most similar to yours given the distance it was recorded (though, he suggests it's a subspecies out of range that was recorded).
- You might also try [Audobon's](https://www.audubon.org/field-guide/bird/barred-owl) sound clips as they were recorded at farther distance than those at Cornell and so better represent what you're hearing.

You're in range of these owls in Port Townsend:

[image]

Source: [All About Birds](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Barred_Owl/maps-range)

Answer (score -1):

No question ; barred owl. There are a few in the subdivision and presently I hear them fairly often. I think it may be fledging practicing the call. I am in  E TX at the southern end of the range on the shown map.

Answer (score -2):

It could be the Sri Lankan spot-bellied eagle-owl lost in America.

Link = [https://www.google.com/search?q=spot-bellied+eagle-owl&oq=spot-bellied+eagle-owl&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0i22i30l7.931j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8][1]

Comment: Welcome to the site!  It would be much better to embed the image in your post; the google query will change over time.  Please [edit] in the picture.  Thanks!

Comment: Given the similarity of the call to a bird known to live in the area this seems at best extremely speculative. You are also more likely to get a positive response if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated calls. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and thus off-topic. ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you!